# Recursively list all functions and aliases used in specific function

Tags: bash

I want to recursively list all self-defined functions and aliases used in specific function in Bash to share the script with friends, blogs.

I have a function which includes a lots of dependencies, functions and aliaes.
For exeample, following one is using a lots of functions and aliaes.

```
calc3 " round ( ( $( printf -- "%s+" $( ps fux | awk 3 | tail -n +2 ) | chomplastchar ) ) ) "
```

As first level, following functions/aliases are used in.

```
alias calc3='pythonprint3'


awk () 
{ 
    : e.g. `# something | awk 2 `;
    : e.g. `# something | awk nr2 `;
    [[ "${1}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && { 
        /usr/bin/awk -v var="${1}" '{print $var}';
        return 0
    };
    [[ "${1}" =~ ^nr[0-9]+$ ]] && { 
        /usr/bin/awk "NR==${1##+([a-z])}";
        return 0
    };
    /usr/bin/awk "$@" && { 
        return 0
    }
}


chomplastchar () 
{ 
    chomp | python3 -c "import json,sys;print(sys.stdin.read()[:-1])"
}
```

Then, in above functions, `pythonprint3` and `chomp`, both are also self-defined functions as well.

basically, I want info about all of self-defined functions/aliases. In this case, desired result is something like following. Any idea?

```
calc3
awk
chomplastchar
pythonprint3
chomp
```

Comment: Can be easily done with `type` command. For instance, when you execute `type calc3`, it would return `calc3 is aliased to pythonprint3` and for binaries like `round` or commands defined by you it would return path and for functions, it would show the complete definition.

Comment: I know that. I want to do that something like `type calc3 awk pythonprint3` after looking up all of used  functions as above.

Comment: `( declare -f; alias; ) > before; : define function; ( declare -f; alias; ) > after; diff before after` ?

Comment: all of self-defined functions are defined in .bashrc at same time, not manually. so there is no way to do that.